Inconsistent *ngIf behaviour when I initialise objects using data in URL fragment
I am creating a fairly simple Angular SPA search tool where users can manually enter search fields, or fields can be auto-populated by pulling data (e.g. search string and search type) out of a URL fragment. This is to allow bookmarking of searches.
After the URL fragment is populated and the page loads, the search automatically starts. Since I implemented this, I get weird behaviour with *ngIf. This behaviour is fixed by using data binding instead. e.g. [disabled]="<condition>".
For example, when a search is performed via the manual search method, the following correct behaviour occurs in order to display the number of results:

The number of search results is initially shown as (0)
The user enters data and clicks search, and (0) is replaced with a loading spinner e.g. ()
When the http request finishes, the spinner replaced with the number of results, e.g. (150)

However, when a url fragment triggers the search, this is the behaviour:

The search is automatically initiated and (  0 ) is displayed (incorrectly)
The search finishes and shows the correct result, e.g. (150)

Since this occurs due to the following code, I don't understand how this could be happening.
<span *ngIf="loading" class="spinner-border spinner-border-sm" role="status">
      <span class="sr-only"></span>
</span>
<span *ngIf="!loading">{{ resultsCounts[currentTab] }}</span>

I have tried showing the results of the *ngIf expression on the webpage, and they are as expected. However regardless of this, both of the spans are shown on the webpage ONLY when searching via URL fragment. For example, <div>{{ loading }} </div> displays true, but <span *ngIf="!loading">{{ resultsCounts[currentTab] }}</span> is still displayed on the webpage.
This weirdness occurs in many different places, with other html elements repeated when they are displayed on an *ngIf condition.
Here is how I access the fragment in my component:
fragment: string | null;

constructor(private searchApiService: SearchApiService, private route: ActivatedRoute) {
        this.fragment = this.route.snapshot.fragment;
}

ngOnInit() {
        // if fragment was populated, perform auto-search, otherwise do nothing
        if (this.fragment) {
        // -- omitted string processing of fragment to extract search data here --
        this.searchApiService.search();
        }
    }

Please let me know if anyone knows why this is happening. As I mentioned, I can fix these issues by using data binding to show/hide elements instead of *ngIf, but I suspect that the fact that things are behaving so weirdly indicates that I'm doing something very wrong. I am new to web dev, so any insights are greatly appreciated. Thank you.

could you please add a code where loading is updated?

you should probably do this from constructor... it's likely these are queryParams... I use something like  this.loading = false; this.route.queryParams
.subscribe(params => {  ... call service to set viewstate from params... then call this.searchApiService.search(viewstate); });  My viewstate holds a bunch of properties like sortBy, sortDir, searchTerm, searchType, etc... [key: string]: any; to conform with queryParams... display initializes/changes according to viewstate.

thanks @browsermator. I went with a similar solution of just changing things after loading===false, but I still don't understand why that would be necessary. Thanks for the response though

when/if only changing hash, (so same path before "#")  angular will not call constructor or ngOninit.  (It doesn't need to as routed path has not changed...)  Hashchange will fire though.  That's where ActivatedRoute does it's stuff, and you can subscribe to those changes... loading will retain previous state.  (maybe just a bug/quirk in your case where false becomes a string?)
